# Check boolean attributes in all child objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, parent-child, has-many

I have a Meeting model which has multiple Participants. Participant has a few boolean attributes: accepted, rejected ect. I would like check all participants of a meeting if their are all accepted == true. 
Is there a quick way to check all boolean attributes of child objects similar to sum method (as in total_price = items.sum(&:price) )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count):

```
all_true = items.count(:conditions => [ 'bool_column = ?', true ]) == items.count
```

And if you don't have NULLs to worry about in your boolean column:

```
all_true = items.count(:conditions => [ 'bool_column = ?', false ]) == 0
```

Or you could do it this way (as suggested by [klochner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110213/klochner)) to get around the usual NULL problems and avoid a double `count`:

```
all_true = items.count(:conditions => [ 'bool_column = ? or bool_column is null', false ]) == 0
```

You could check several boolean columns at once too.

Comment: the second version would work with null if you just add "bool_column is null or bool_column = ?",false

Comment: @klochner: Right, thanks for pointing that out, I've patched the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

```
meeting.participants.all?(&:acctepted)
```

Take a look at the [enumerable module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

Comment: just be aware that this solution loads all participants into memory and then loops through them, as opposed to the (better) solution from mu below, which should be log(n)

Comment: depends on the situation. if the participants are already loaded my solution does not bother the DB with an extra query, if not mu's solution is better.

Comment: Thanks klockner. I didn't realized.

Comment: @topek - no argument there, I assumed he was just working with the Meeting model, but you are correct about not hitting the db if participants are loaded